# Google Drive access log (access times and IP addresses anywhere?)

Tags: gmail, google-drive

In Gmail it is possible to view a list of dates and times of last access together with the corresponding IP addresses. I would like to know whether the same feature is available for Google Drive. I see an ACTIVITY window on the right-hand-side (which can also be closed and then reopened by clicking on the square gray button with an *i* and a circle around the *i*). But such panel only shows the latest dates and times of creations, modifications, and uploads, whereas I would also like to see the dates of last access or at least dates of accesses to Google drive together with the corresponding IP address (as in Gmail).

---

As you can see from the screenshot posted below, from the country I am staying in the name of the region/province is shown instead of the city name, and what is worse is that no IP address is shown https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity. And the information seems inaccurate for other reasons as well (for instance, it's been at least about 10 days that I've switched from Firefox to Chrome, but the logs still show Firefox as my web browser!):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't such a log specifically for Google Drive.

However, there's a security log for the Google account in general, showing all devices that have logged in to the account. In https://myaccount.google.com/ you can find a [device list](https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity) and [security events](https://security.google.com/settings/security/notifications).

[image]

Comment: Thanks. As a matter of fact I can see the list of devices I've used to access my account, but cannot see the IP addresses of these. For instance, I can see the name given to my Android devices appear there, but for my PC the name shows up as simply "Windows", and does not display the computer's name. The actual IP would be good if it could be shown as well. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but do you know whether there is a fix for showing the IP address as well (and perhaps also the computer name of the Windows computer used to access your Google account)? Anyways, at least the country and region from which the access took place is recorded, thus providing some detail, but this doesn't help if someone else accesses your account from within the same region or city or even from a different Winodws PC running behind a router where the IP address is shared. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Websites generally can't know the computer name [without using Java or other plugins], so no.

Comment: Well, if this were the case, how come the names (or model names, which act as the default name) of my Android devices actually show up? Why can't Windows do the same thing as these Android devices do? Can't HTTP headers be used to send the computer name? And what about the actual IP addresses, why are they not there?

Comment: "how come the names (or model names, which act as the default name) of my Android devices actually show up?" Because Android has Google sign-on as part of the OS, not confined within the browser.

Comment: "Why can't Windows do the same thing as these Android devices do?" It does, just not with Google accounts – but with Microsoft accounts. Last I checked, Microsoft doesn't have any plans to join the Google world just yet.

Comment: "Can't HTTP headers be used to send the computer name?" Sure, they *can*, but browsers *won't* do that for privacy reasons.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, but I still don't get why Gmail can show the IP addresses while Google Drive cannot. Where does the difference lie? Thanks.

Comment: The difference lies in Gmail developers having devoted some of their time to create the activity log (which was done before the global security log existed), and Google Drive developers deciding to rely on the global one instead.

Comment: "And what about the actual IP addresses, why are they not there?" http://i.stack.imgur.com/CC4sD.png

Comment: Please see my screenshot. Indeed, the IP address is not there, the city name isn't either, and the browser client information is plain wrong.